# Unable to debug GWT from eclipse

Tags: java, gwt

The app is not stopping at any of the breakpoints I set. GWT 2.3.0, Eclipse 3.6, Jdk 1.6.26. I am running DevMode.

THank you.

Comment: This does seem to happen some times... Stop the dev server and start it again and it should work. You can try shutting down Eclipse and starting it again. See if that helps.. usually works for me.

Comment: @filip-fku did this multiple times but it didn't help. even the sysout and syserr's are not being logged to console

Comment: Are you sure you are running in dev mode? Can you show us your browser URL?

Comment: @maneesh - yes in dev mode . here is the url http://127.0.0.1:8888/Funpluscharity.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: Debug As -> Web application?
I ask, because as I remember, in my eclipse with GWT installed (laptop left at work) there is also option to debug gwt application and it didn't work for me.

Comment: It only happens to me if I launch with run instead of debug.

Comment: @Piotrek De yes debug as web application

Comment: Are you using pure GWT or Some ext like extGwt?Does any error pops out in the Console?please clean and build the application and also from Jconsole please maximize the heap usuage and go to the services.msc(in case of Windows) and stop and restart the service and try once more...plz be specific of the question,what type of AS are you using too?

Answer (score 0):

Does your Application contain any navigation links to other URLs in your Application,
if this links doesn't contain the gwt.codesvr parameter then debugging stops working.